# System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

Is there any thing missing in my connection string so that i am getting this error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.

This is my connection String in web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="OnlineStoreEntities" connectionString="Data Source=SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MVCOnlineShop;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="MVCOnlineShop" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ShopModel.csdl|res://*/Models.ShopModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.ShopModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=AHMADZAKARIA-PC;initial catalog=MVCOnlineShop;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: what is the inner exception?

Comment: @jαsοndιnAlt , i am getting this on ToList(), but why?

Answer (score 3):

Check your connection string in `*.config` file and most probably you are missing the `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`. See [Entity Framework Config File Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj556606(v=vs.113).aspx) for more information

Comment: in connectionstrings section or config section? @Rahul

Comment: @AhmadZakaria, check both of them ... go through the linked MSDN documentation

Comment: i will edit my question and add my connection strings, please check it @Rahul