# Connection String Form to an SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, asp.net-mvc-4, connection-string

i want to connect to database in an SQL server, so is the form of this connection string correct:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="OnlineStoreEntities" connectionString="Data Source=SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MVCOnlineShop;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="MVCOnlineShop" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ShopModel.csdl|res://*/Models.ShopModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.ShopModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=AHMADZAKARIA-PC;initial catalog=MVCOnlineShop;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Why do you get that doubt ? is it failing ?

Comment: Yes! Both are correct.

Comment: yeah because i am getting an entity exception, and saying that it can occur due to incorrect connection string @Krishna

Comment: why am i getting the entity exception? @BasantaMatia

Comment: can you show the exception ? And to which connection string you get exception first or second  ?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.  @Krishna

Comment: check this , i have posted an earlier question about this problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44945937/system-data-providerincompatibleexception-in-entity-framework   , @Krishna

Comment: I think you are pointing your entity framework to the top one, why do you have two connection strings ?

Comment: the database in my server is MVCOnlineShop , so which one should i use , sorry for these questions , but i am a beginner in mvc web , thanks! @Krishna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your names as below

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MVCOnlineShop" connectionString="Data Source=SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MVCOnlineShop;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="OnlineStoreEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ShopModel.csdl|res://*/Models.ShopModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.ShopModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=AHMADZAKARIA-PC;initial catalog=MVCOnlineShop;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: you are welcome, try to remove the other connection string which is redundant

Comment: i tried , but it didn't work , but how can i have 2 connection strings and still working ? @Krishna

Comment: you said it worked just now ? but now you say it's not working ?

Comment: Also why do you need 2 connection string ? if you want you can have them I just told to avoid confusion

Comment: i meant i tried 1 connection string , and didn't work, but when having 2 connection strings as you told me , they are working @krishna

Comment: which one you kept and which one you removed ?

Comment: OnlineStoreEntities is used by entityframework and I am not sure what's using the other one

Comment: i kept mvconlineshop and remove onlinestoreentities, how can i make mvc online shop used by entity framework? @Krishna

Comment: entityframework by default takes name from the entity model name which is "onlinestoreentities", if you want to change you need to specify it when instantiating the database context

Comment: oh ok , i have in my dbcontext online store entities yeah , can i keep them both? , or should i change the online store entities in the dbcontext to MVCOnlineShop? @krishna

Comment: you can always keep any number of them, but don't confuse between. btw, don't forget to upvote and mark as answer

Comment: done , Ty very much @Krishna , really appreciated , +rep me please too

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to place

```
Data Source=SERVERNAME\\SQLEXPRESS;
```

Comment: still getting this :
An exception of type 'System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in the data source you specified in those to connection strings.
- in the first connection string you have written SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS 
- in the second one, your data source is AHMADZAKARIA-PC .
Put the same info in both connections: based on the short info you gave us, you should use AHMADZAKARIA-PC or AHMADZAKARIA-PC\SQLEXPRESS